# comparing two files with awk side by side and to get out put expected

Tags: shell, awk

I have 2 files 1.xml and 2.xml. Files are sorted and differ in length. I want to use awk for comparing and print matching and non matching lines in expected format.

1.xml

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> allowedAudit == false`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> allowedAudit == false`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> horizontalAccuracy == 100`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> horizontalAccuracy == 50`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> id == 1`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> id == 2`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> ionosphericModelAllowed == true`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxNumGPSSatellites == 8`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxNumGPSSatellites == 8`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxUeBasedAGPSProcedureTime == 24`

2.xml

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> allowedAudit == false`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> allowedAudit == true`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> horizontalAccuracy == 120`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> horizontalAccuracy == 50`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> id == 1`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> id == 3`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> ionosphericModelAllowed == true`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxNumGPSSatellites == 8`

Code used

```
awk -F"==" 'FNR==NR { array1[$1]=$2;array[$2]=$2; next } { print ($2 in array ? $0 : $0" "array1[$1]" ""NM"), array[$2] }' 2.xml 1.xml
```

Output

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> allowedAudit == false  false`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> allowedAudit == false  false`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> horizontalAccuracy == 100  50 NM`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> horizontalAccuracy == 50  50`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> id == 1  1`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> id == 2  3 NM`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> ionosphericModelAllowed == true  true`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxNumGPSSatellites == 8  8`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxNumGPSSatellites == 8  8`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxUeBasedAGPSProcedureTime == 24  NM`

Expected Output

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> allowedAudit == false  false`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> allowedAudit == false  false`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> horizontalAccuracy == 100  120 NM`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> horizontalAccuracy == 50  50`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> id == 1  1`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> id == 2  3 NM`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> ionosphericModelAllowed == true  true`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxNumGPSSatellites == 8  8`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxNumGPSSatellites == 8  NF`

`AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxUeBasedAGPSProcedureTime == 24 NF`

Need extra piece of code for non matching lines as Not Found(NF)

Also the logic fails for some non matching cases(NM) but for some cases it works.

The actual file is large one and I am getting partial success.

Comment: Please use multi-line code formatting instead of starting and ending a code-formatted section for each individual line; this is hard-to-read and hard-to-edit.

Comment: ...also, please ask about a specific problem you had when implementing the desired logic _yourself_. Don't just show your data and describe you want done with it -- that's a job for a paid contractor, not a Q&A database.

Comment: both files have duplicate values for `$1` and `$2` which means during processing of the first file (`FNR==NR`) successive array assignments are overwriting previous array assignments; what's the logic you plan to use to match rows between files when the fields you're matching have duplicates?

Comment: [Canonical XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML) can be used to compare pairs of XML docs, e.g. [tag:xmlstarlet] supports a `c14n` command.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F' == ' 'NR==FNR {a[$1,++c[$1]]=$2; next} 
                        {print $1 FS $2, v=a[$1,++d[$1]], (v!=$2)?"NM":""; 
                         delete a[$1,d[$1]]} 
                END     {for(k in a) 
                           {split(k,ks,SUBSEP); 
                            print ks[1] FS a[k],"NF"}}' file1 file2

AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> allowedAudit == false false
AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> allowedAudit == true false NM
AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> horizontalAccuracy == 120 100 NM
AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> horizontalAccuracy == 50 50
AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> id == 1 1
AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> id == 3 2 NM
AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> ionosphericModelAllowed == true true
AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxNumGPSSatellites == 8 8
AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxNumGPSSatellites == 8 NF
AGPS=1_<Class>_AGPS -> maxUeBasedAGPSProcedureTime == 24 NF
```

This accounts for duplicate keys by adding a counter as part of key.  Matching is by coordinating the counters.  Eventually excess records are printed as NF.

*PS.* your expected output for record 2 is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Karakfa for the solution. Yes I do mind later that the expected output for record 2 was wrong.